# Magento2 - How can I convert default Magento cart icon into simple text like Cart?

Tags: magento2, css, mini-cart, less-css

I need to convert the cart icon having the following CSS

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{
font-size: 35px;
line-height: 33px;
color: #8f8f8f;
content: '\e611';
font-family: 'icons-blank-theme';
margin: 0;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;}
```

[image: current icon]

into simple text  like Cart(0)
[image: convert it into text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide icon using CSS, please don't remove the class action show cart from your override phtml file i.e  `<a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"` it will remove the icon but pop up will not open.

please try the below CSS to remove cart icon.

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart::before,
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart.active::before{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the hide the icon but want to replace it with text

Comment: doing this The cart is hidden

Comment: have you override minicart.phtml ?

Comment: <a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"  Its already the same as the line in minicart.phtml

Comment: ok, please blank the action show class like this  <a class=" " href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"  & let me know

Comment: & please don't forget to clean the cache.    php bin/magento c:c

Comment: Thanks It is done

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property `content` is creating a cart icon just remove it

```
.minicart-wrapper .action.showcart:before{
font-size: 35px;
line-height: 33px;
color: #8f8f8f;
font-family: 'icons-blank-theme';
margin: 0;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: I have removed content element but still it is the same

Comment: run `php bin/magento cache:flush` in your root folder and try again

Comment: done but still no result

Comment: how are doing using using custom modeulr or overriding the theme?

Comment: Over riding the theme